# Expected value of the ratio of shifted Bernoulli variables

Tags: self-study, expected-value, bernoulli-distribution

Have two independent Bernoulli variables $X,Y$

I'm trying to calculate $$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\frac{X+1}{Y+1}\bigg]$$

Given $X,Y$ are independent, this can be split into:

$$\mathbb{E}[X+1]\mathbb{E}\bigg[\frac{1}{Y+1}\bigg]$$

But is this the way to go on evaluating this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you write down the values taken by $\frac{1}{Y+1}$ and the associated probabilities?

Can you then write down its expectation?

Can you write down $E[{X+1}]$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be Bernoulli($p_x$) and $Y$ be Bernoulli($p_y$).

Then $E[X] = 1*p_x + 0*(1-p_x) = P(X=1) = p_x$

and $E[Y] = 1*p_y + 0*(1-p_y) = P(Y=1) = p_y$

1. $$E[X+1] = E[X] + 1 = P(X=1) + 1  $$
2. $$E\left[\frac{1}{Y+1}\right] = \sum_{\text{y in Range of Y}} \frac{1}{y+1} P(Y=y)$$

$$= \sum_{y=0}^{1} \frac{1}{y+1} P(Y=y) = \frac{1}{1+1}P(Y=1) + \frac{1}{0+1}P(Y=0)$$

$$= \frac 1 2 p_y + (1-p_y) = 1 - \frac 1 2 p_y$$

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short. Can you expand on it with some text that explicates the equations?

Comment: @BCLC "Automatically" means "by the SE software". Please avoid personal commentary on our site.

Comment: However, it's still necessary to try to adhere to the guidelines for answers to [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) questions --- specifically, "hints and guidance" rather than explicit answers.

Comment: @Glen_b I agree which is why I gave such an answer in the first place but then...

Comment: ... @gung told me to expand Soooo...

Comment: Yes, I saw all of that; I was explaining the difficult course you need to steer in doing so.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Your answer came up in the low quality review queue. I didn't navigate over here & so I didn't see that it was self-study. But I did think it was actually an answer & didn't need to be deleted. So I left a comment & edited it to remove it from the queue before others deleted it.